# Why does "git pull" fail if the master branch also checked in the exact same file?

Tags: git

I accidentally added the same file to a git repo from two different machines.  On  Machine A added/committed/pushed it to a central repo.  Machine B did the add and commit, then I did a "pull".

If I do this with text files, git does a merge (which works very well, since the files are the same).  I assume the merge is required because the commit messages aren't exactly the same.  I tried to make them the same and found that even if I set the datestamp to be the same on both commits they get different commit hashes.  That said, git does a clean merge and is happy.

If I do this with a binary file (for example, a PDF), git sees that the file exists in both places and just gives up.

Here is a transcript of what happened on Machine B with a binary file:

```
$ git pull --rebase
remote: Counting objects: 24, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (18/18), done.
From ssh://redacted.org/home/git/tposana3
   7c8fa64..480fff1  master     -> origin/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
  edition3/vol2/reviews/vol2-18-capacityplan-DE.pdf
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
could not detach HEAD
$ cd ../reviews/
$ mv vol2-18-capacityplan-DE.pdf vol2-18-capacityplan-DE.pdf.NOT
$ git pull --rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded master to 480fff14f9462bc5dd975d27e328dcd9ce89f2ff.
tlimwork:~/gitthings/tposana3/edition3/vol2/reviews$ md5 *vol2-18-*
MD5 (vol2-18-capacityplan-DE.pdf) = 521d2d9839bbbaa269b11eaddaacc904
MD5 (vol2-18-capacityplan-DE.pdf.NOT) = 521d2d9839bbbaa269b11eaddaacc904
```

As you can see the files are bit-for-bit the same.

I understand that git would say, "oh!  these are binary files.  I'm not even going to try to merge them!" however since the files are bit-for-bit the same, shouldn't it be able to have the same behavior as with text files?

Answer (score 1):

It's not trying to merge them, nor does it make any difference whether the file is binary or not.  Git is performing a check of the files that would be affected by the merge and looking in the working directory to determine if there are any untracked files in those locations.

In your case, there is, and this is a problem.  It doesn't bother looking at the working directory contents, because you're not in a state where you should be merging things.

If this file were committed, or staged, you would see the behavior you're expecting.  But an untracked file is precious.